# If $a$ is an integer, prove that $gcd(14a + 3, 21a + 4) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

If $a$ is an integer, prove that $gcd(14a + 3, 21a + 4) = 1$

-We have just started the section on greatest common divisor, one thing I know is that $gcd(a,b) = ax + by$

-My initial thought is that we would plug our values into that equation to get the following:

$$(14a + 3)x + (21a + 4)y = 1$$

-I am a bit confused as to how to proceed though, as I assume that I have to prove this for all values of a. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Euclides algorythm.

Comment: We solved similar examples in class using the Euclidean algorithm, although we only did it with single numbers not functions. How would i proceed?

Comment: 14a and 21a should make it an  *obvious* choice to start with x = 3 and y = -2.  $(14a + 3)3 - (21a + 4)2 = 9 - 8 = 1$ so we are done.  $14a = 2*7a; 21a = 3*7a$ so $14a*2 = 21a*3$ really should have made it *very* obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Euclidean algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanAlgorithm.html):
\begin{align}
\gcd(14a+3,21a+4)&=\gcd(14a+3,7a+1)\\
&=\gcd(7a+1,1)\\
&=1
\end{align}

Equivalently, and more directly,
\begin{align}
(14a+3)(3)+(21a+4)(-2)&=(42a+9)-(42a+8)\\
&=1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$21a + 4= 14a + 3 +7a+1\implies \gcd(14a + 3, 21a + 4) = \gcd(14a + 3, 7a + 1).$$

$$14a + 3= 7a + 1 +7a+2\implies  \gcd(14a + 3, 7a + 1)=\gcd(7a + 2, 7a + 1).$$

$$7a + 2= 7a + 1 +1\implies  \gcd(7a + 2, 7a + 1)=\gcd(7a + 1, 1)=1.$$

Comment: In your last line, you meant $7a + 2 = 7a + 1 + \color{red}{1}$.  Also, you can produce $\gcd$ by typing \gcd in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes. Thank you very much for noticing the typo and the help to improve format.